# Sheet#copyTo(Spreadsheet) raises Service Error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I simply want to copy a template sheet and rename it when the script identifies that a sheet is missing.

8th line (with the `copyTo`) isn't working. I get this error message:

> Service error: Spreadsheets (line 202, file "statsContacts")

Similar questions on S.O. indicate an issue with Range#copyTo but that's a different method.

N.B.1: in finale version "communautes" and "feuillesExistantes" will be generated dynamically
N.B.2: I added the polyfill of `Array.prototype.includes` to be able to use it

```
function creerFeuillesManquantes(){
  var communautes = ['ESSAI', 'TEST', 'FOO'];
  var feuillesExistantes = ['Catégorie ESSAI', 'Catégorie TEST'];
  for (c in communautes){
    if (!feuillesExistantes.includes(communautes[c])){
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var template = ss.getSheetByName('TEMPLATE');  
      var newSheet = template.copyTo(ss);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // avant de renommer, on s'assure que la copie soit faite
      newSheet.setName('Catégorie '+communautes[c]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does the designated sheet already exist, i.e. is there already a `Copy of TEMPLATE` sheet in the active workbook?

Comment: No, no such sheet exists, just the 'TEMPLATE'.

Comment: Is it on the first call? Second? Third? Only this workbook? Only these sheet names? Only when you use `flush`? Only when the source workbook is the same as the destination? Provide some additional debugging information.

Comment: Thanks tehhowch. The problem was that I couldn't get more debugging info with my current knowledge. In the end I was reaching the 5M cap. I resized and problem solved now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing to the following:

```
function creerFeuillesManquantes(){
  var communautes = ['ESSAI', 'TEST', 'FOO'];
  var feuillesExistantes = ['Catégorie ESSAI', 'Catégorie TEST'];

  // move ss and template up to avoid making network calls every time
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var template = ss.getSheetByName('TEMPLATE');

  for (c in communautes){
    if (!feuillesExistantes.includes(communautes[c])){
      ss.insertSheet('Catégorie '+communautes[c], { template: template });
      SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // avant de renommer, on s'assure que la copie soit faite
    }
  }
}
```

I found that, when I switched to `ss.insertSheet(...)` instead of `template.copyTo(...)`, I received much better error messages, e.g. `This action would increase the number of cells in the workbook above the limit of 5000000 cells.`.

Comment: This helped thanks! Indeed I was reaching 5M cells when creating multiple sheets. I resized the template to something more viable and problem solved.

Comment: Really helpful answer! Weird that using copyTo (which is how I came across this) gives such a useless error.